# DB2 Tablespace with Bufferpool Error (SQLSTATE=42601)

Tags: db2, tablespace

I am trying to create a tablespace using a predefined bufferpool on my DB2 11.1.
Unfortunately, I am receiving an Error even when trying many different combinations. The result is the same wether I use a SQLClient or the db2 terminal (user-admin is db2inst1).

My Statements:

```
CREATE BUFFERPOOL POOL32 SIZE 32000 PAGESIZE 32768; // Successful
commit;

CREATE TABLESPACE mytablespace PAGESIZE 32K MANAGED BY DATABASE USING (FILE '/tmp/mytablespace' 100000) BUFFERPOOL POOL32;
```

The Error:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0109N  The statement or command was not processed because the following
clause is not supported in the context where it is used: "MANAGED BY
DATABASE".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

#### UPDATE:

To answer some of the comments:

- Version is IBM Db2 Developer-C 11.1.4.4 and Platform is Linux/Unix, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6
- I have tried to use automatic storage, but if I just define it without pagesize (or maybe initialsize) I will get an Error during the software database initialization, where a table create statement reaches the maximum pagesize (therefore I wanted to use the Bufferpool and file dms since it still worked with an oracle db):

-

```
CREATE LARGE TABLESPACE MYTABLESPACE MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE;
commit;
```

Which results in this pagelimit error:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0286N  A table space could not be found with a page size of at least "4096"
that authorization ID "DB2INST1" is authorized to use.  SQLSTATE=42727
```

[All Tablespaces Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVyjM.png)

- If I try to use an "automatic storage" tablespace using a command from the IBM site (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0024250.html), I am recieving a 'wrong syntax' error:

-

```
CREATE TABLESPACE TS3 INITIALSIZE 8K INCREASESIZE 20 PERCENT MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE
```

With the error here:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "INITIALSIZE 8K INCREASESIZE 20 PERCENT" was
found following "REATE TABLESPACE TS3".  Expected tokens may include:
"<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Comment: This is an admin type question. Maybe you should ask at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is this Developer-C edition? If yes, then what’s fixpack?

Comment: Why choose a file dms solution ? That feature is deprecated and may be removed in a future version. Switch to automatic storage.

Comment: It works on a RHEL 7.5 + Db2 V11.1 Mod4 FP4a without the error.  Which platform? Db2 version, db2level output?